# Serializing xml to object while keeping the original xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlreader

I'm using an external API to receive xml and serializing this to an object but I want a way to be able to keep the original xml used to serialize for debugging and auditing.

Here's a sample of how I'm serializing:

```
XmlReader reader = this.Execute(url);
return Read<Property>(reader, "property");
```

Extract of Execute() routine:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(s);
return reader;
```

Read() simply wraps up the native xml serialization:

```
private T Read<T>(XmlReader reader, string rootElement)
{
  XmlRootAttribute root = new XmlRootAttribute();
  root.ElementName = rootElement;
  root.IsNullable = true;
  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), root);
  object result = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
  return (T)result;
}
```

I've had a look around at it appears once you've used the reader, you can't use it again (forward only reading stream?). Without trying to change to much, how can I extract the contents of the reader as xml while still benefiting from the built in serialization with the reader?

What would be nice is to adjust Read with an out param:

```
private T Read<T>(XmlReader reader, string rootElement, out string sourceXml);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not share the code for this.Execute(url), but presumably you build a reader from a stream.  First write that stream to a string, then use it somewhere.  If the stream is not seekable, dispose it and create a new stream from it.

Also, note that XmlSerializer can take a stream instead of a reader, so you could never bother with the reader and just pass streams among your methods.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip about the stream - i'll remove the extra logic to build the reader and just use the stream directly. When you say write it to a string, does that mean I can re-use it?

Comment: Well, I assume the string form of the XML is pretty small since you are doing this, and holding it in memory is not going to be a big deal.  Given that assumption, start with reading it all into a string (presumably the one you want it to be in.  Then read that string into a new MemoryStream.  See this link for string-stream conversions: http://www.csharp411.com/c-convert-string-to-stream-and-stream-to-string/

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've tried cloning the stream but it doens't seem to work - i'll extract the xml as a string and use that rather than the reader (when debugging anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Fiddler is a Web Debugging Proxy which logs all HTTP(S) traffic between your computer and the Internet. Fiddler allows you to inspect traffic, set breakpoints, and "fiddle" with incoming or outgoing data. Fiddler includes a powerful event-based scripting subsystem, and can be extended using any .NET language.